# How to run a binary file with python script

Tags: python, binary, operating-system, subprocess, popen

**Code: terminal**

```
./foldx_20221231 --command=Stability --pdb=./input_file.pdb --out-pdb=1
```

**Code: python**

```
import os
import subprocess

# path
input_file='./input_file.pdb'
path_foldx_scores_out=f'{path_input_file}/foldx.fxout'
path_foldx='Tool/foldx5/foldx_20221231'
path_foldx_softlink=f'{source}/foldx_20221231'

# 10-1.run foldx
with open(path_foldx_scores_out, 'w') as out_stream:
    os.symlink(path_foldx, path_foldx_softlink)
    execute_foldx=subprocess.Popen([path_foldx_softlink, '--command=Stability', f'--pdb={input_file}', '--out-pdb=1'], stdout=out_stream) 
    execute_foldx.wait()
```

**Created files: terminal**

```
input_file_0_ST.fxout, rotabase.txt
```

**Created file: python**

```
foldx.fxout

(context in foldx.fxout file)
No pdbs for the run found at:
"./"
Foldx will end
```

I'm trying to get result by running the foldx binary file with python script, not terminal. When I tried to execute foldx on terminal, it works well enough. However, with python script, I couldn't get the results like the results from terminal. Could you let me know what can I do in this situation?

Comment: Can you construct the command, store it in a variable, print it, then pass it to `subprocess.Popen` ? It should look exactly like `['./foldx_20221231', '--command=Stability', '--pdb=./input_file.pdb', '--out-pdb=1']`. It is a great way to see if the problem comes from bad arguments.